# TensorFlow - Advantages to a certain language

Tags: tensorflow

I am researching into using TensorFlow and am trying to decide which language to write in.

I am currently using Clojure in my day job (I know you can use Java so should I check out a Clojure wrapper). I have also started to learn Haskell. As TensorFlow is very mathematically based maybe Haskell would be the best language to write it in.

I have read that TensorFlow is mainly written in C++ and so Python is the main language that people use.

Is it best to write TensorFlow in Python or does Clojure/Java or Haskell work just as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what your use case is.

For exploring machine learning concepts or for doing machine learning research Python is your best bet. It has the most features, documentation and user base to help with support.

Java and some other language bindings are geared more towards integrating models with existing code (into production pipelines, apps, your-other-production servers etc.) and don't have the convenience of breadth of API that Python provides (quoting from the [api documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/) - "The Python API is at present the most complete and the easiest to use, but other language APIs may be easier to integrate into projects and may offer some performance advantages in graph execution.")

The Haskell bindings might be interesting, but again, if you're exploring TensorFlow, you're probably better off with Python to begin with. If and when you need to integrate models into other software, you will be able to export them from Python and import/execute them in other languages.

Hope that helps.